# How to publish asp.net application with Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I try to publish the site via ftp method and there are some options that i do not know how to complete them.

The inputs are

- server
- sitepath
- username and password i assume it is the ftp credentials
- and destination url

and secondly how the heck am i going to upload my database? Am I going to use SQL Server Management Studio?

Thank you.

I experimented with many different values for the input but no lack!

Answer (score 6):

Please follow these steps to deploy asp.net with via visual studio 2019 using FTP.

1. In Visual Studio, on the Build menu, click Publish
2. On the Publish page, click the icon labeled IIS, FTP, etc.
3. Click Publish.
4. From Connection Tab, select FTP as Publish Method list box.
5. In the Server text box, type the protocol, server domain name, and port:(ftp://abc.com:990) etc [All versions of Visual Studio assume port 21 is the default port. You must specify port 990 in the Server text box for a successful connection.]
6. In the Site Path text box, type the file location where the site files should be stored. For the primary domain of an account, the path is /httpdocs but it could be any path that you have set up:
7. Select the Passive mode check box if it is not already selected:
8. In the Username text box, type the FTP username, and password in Password field.
9. Optionally, in the Destination URL text box, type the URL for the uploaded site:(http//:abc.com) etc
10. Click Validate Connection. A green checkmark appears when validation is successful and Click Next.
11. On the Settings tab, select any additional options that you want. None of the settings are required to continue.
12. After making any desired settings, click Save.
13. The FTPS upload begins immediately, and you can view progress in the Output panel.

Comment: thank you for the detailed step by step explanation. i think the destination url is to open the website page in browser after publish is done. it seems to open a new tab even when the tab it opened previously is still open. not sure wy this wasnt marked as solution or upvoted. but +1 from me.